# Odd blending result (semi-transparent 2d quad over 3D scene)

Tags: opengl, shaders, lwjgl, transparency, alpha

I'm working on a GUI library for my game, and I'm having problems with my blending.

I have a 3D scene, which I render with glDrawArrays. In the fragment shader the alpha color is hardcoded 1.0f (gl_FragColor).

When I render a 2D quad on my screen with 1.0f in the alpha channel, my quad is semi-transparent, while it should be completely opaque.

I render the quad with the basic glBegin(GL_QUADS) and glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f).

I enabled blending with the function:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is my quad semi-transparent?

Screenshot:
[image: Why is my quad semi-transparent?]

Fragment shader:

```
#version 130
varying vec2 texture_coordinate;
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    vec3 textureColor = texture2D(texture, texture_coordinate).rgb;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor, 1.0f);
}
```

Quad render code:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
        glVertex2f(position.x, position.y + size.y);
        glVertex2f(position.x + size.x, position.y + size.y);
        glVertex2f(position.x + size.x, position.y);
        glVertex2f(position.x, position.y);
    glEnd();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong with what you've shown. I suggest providing more information: • A screenshot of the problem • Your fragment shader code

Comment: Added your suggestions.

Comment: Firstly, did you mean glBegin(GL_QUADS) rather than glEnable(GL_QUADS) (which is invalid). Secondly, can you paste the code that draws the quad?

Comment: Yes I bean glBegin, sorry. Added the quad code.

Comment: FYI, I did a little calculation based on the color values in your screenshot, and the colors inside the rectangle vs. outside are pretty close to `0.2 * vec3(0, 0, 1) + 0.8 * outsideColor` — that is, like an RGBA color of `0, 0, 1, 0.2`. Assuming your screenshot has no color/gamma correction, anyway (which is likely since the colors line up neatly). I suggest looking around your code for where you have the number 0.2 or 0.8, to see where that might have arisen.

Comment: Many thanks, but there is no 0.2 or 0.8 in my project. It looks like my entire blending is f*cked up, as if I try to draw another rectangle on top of the blue one, it shows black no matter what color I assign to it. I'm completely lost.

Comment: Do you have any fragment shader bound when rendering the quad?

Comment: Nope. No shaders. Only for the 3D scene.

Comment: If you disable blending, does the quad render the correct colour?

Comment: Yes, then it will render fine, but I need blending.

Comment: Ok, if you don't have a fragment shader bound, and turning off blending shows it correctly, then you have something else in your state that is messing with the alpha value, since that image could not have been produced if the alpha value was 1. I think you might need to post the setup code to rendering the quad.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9576/discussion-between-basaa-and-elfarto)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with the setup code? gdse suggests me to continue in chat to prevent extended discussions in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long debugging session with Basaa, we discovered that the problem was that texturing was still enabled. We just had to add:

```
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```